# Does local maxima problem cause Simple Hill Climbing algorithm to be stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, heuristics, hill-climbing

For example, I have the following problem:

[image: Initial state and goal state]

The only operators I can apply are:

- Place the uppermost block from the structure down
- Place a block that is not in the structure to the uppermost position of the structure

I have a heuristic function of:

- h(n) = +1 for every supporting block if a block is placed correctly and -1 for every supporting block if a block is placed incorrectly.

In this example, "A" block is placed correctly, hence I get a +3 for each supporting block below A. "D" is placed incorrectly, thus I get a -2. C is placed correctly, I get another +1. Therefore, my heuristic function now returns a value of 3 + 1 - 2 = +2.

Now based on the algorithm [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hill-climbing-algorithm), the algorithm will only **quit when it reaches its goal state** and **that it will only choose the next state as its current state if it yields a better heuristic value**. However, it is no longer possible to proceed in the case I made above. Putting A down from the structure will yield a heuristic value of -1 which is worse than the previous value (+2).

Why did I modify the example? I want to show when we encounter local maxima problem in Simple Hill Climbing algorithm, and **this is a local maxima problem, right?** Another question, as the algorithm says that it will **quit [only] when it reaches its goal state**, it will never quit. **Or is it correct of me to assume that it will also quit when the other neighbouring states no longer give a better result?**

Comment: There is a point in the algorithm description that you missed: "until the goal state is achieved or *no more operators can be applied on the current state*". This should answer all your questions.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I see, I did miss that one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hill Climbing is a local search and guarantees to find optimal solutions for convex problems. For non-convex problems it can get stuck (terminates) in a local optima.

There is an "alternative version" of Hill Climbing called [Enforced Hill Climbing (EHC)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume28/coles07a-html/node5.html) that performs breadth-first search until a more promising state is found to "escape" sich local optima. EHC is often used for non-optimal (satisficing) planning as the search is only stopped if the goal is not reachable.